# Saltstack module is not available

Tags: salt-stack

Trying to run sls but the salt tells me the function is not available

My sls. Must create a mongodump file

```
create-dump:
  module.run:
   - name: docker.run
   - m_name: mongo
   - cmd: 'mongodump --out=/Mongodump
```

when i'm run salt minion state.sls sls
i see:

```
ID: create-dump
    Function: module.run
        Name: docker.run
      Result: False
     Comment: Module function docker.run is not available
     Started: 06:03:40.273781
    Duration: 728.234 ms
     Changes:
```

--Versions

```
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3000

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 1.9.1
       cherrypy: 3.5.0
       dateutil: 2.5.3
      docker-py: 4.3.1
          gitdb: 2.0.0
      gitpython: 2.1.1
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: 0.24.5
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 1.0.6
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.8
   mysql-python: 1.3.7
      pycparser: 2.17
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: 0.24.2
         Python: 3.5.3 (default, Jul  9 2020, 13:00:10)
   python-gnupg: 0.3.9
         PyYAML: 3.12
          PyZMQ: 16.0.2
          smmap: 2.0.1
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.2.1

System Versions:
           dist: debian 9.6
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.9.0-8-amd64
         system: Linux
        version: debian 9.6
```

tried pip3 uninstall docker - not work

If i'm reboot server docker-py downgrade to 1.10.6 version

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `python-docker` is installed on the minion.